# How to give an input-file as argument an read it in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am trying to give an input file as an argument in Python using argparse, but somehow, Im getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
    print('in main, args = ',args)
    input_file = args.input_file
    update_file_input(input_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="less script")
    parser.add_argument('--input_file', required=True, help="input file containing IDs and attributes to change (csv)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print('args is: ',args)
    main()
```

I am calling the script with the following command from command line:

```
python updaterScript.py --input_file myCSVFile.csv
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting an error?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ProjectP/runtime/bin/updaterScript.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ProjectP==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'updaterScript.py')()
  File "/home/ProjectP/runtime/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ProjectP/updaterScript.py", line 10
0, in main
    args = arg_parser.parse_args()
```

NameError: name 'arg_parser' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to call `parse_args()` in two places. Call it once, then pass the result to `main()` as a parameter.

```
def main(args):
    print('in main, args = ',args)
    input_file = args.input_file
    update_file_input(input_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="less script")
    parser.add_argument('--input_file', required=True, help="input file containing IDs and attributes to change (csv)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print('args is: ',args)
    main(args)
```

There's no reason that I can see to split the code between `main()` and the `if` block. I would just put it all in one place and move the `import` to the top of the file.

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="less script")
    parser.add_argument('--input_file', required=True, help="input file containing IDs and attributes to change (csv)")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print('args is: ',args)

    input_file = args.input_file
    update_file_input(input_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your args which is actually arg_parser.parse_args() is not defined. Do you import or have from somewhere the arg_parser?
Can you debug and see what arg_parser.parse_args() returns?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your code, there's no logical reason that it **would** recognize arg_parse.
You are not importing it or initializing it at any point of your (seen) code.
I don't get what you're trying to do there.
Where did you come up with arg_parse?